# Reputation Purchase

Tags: bug, reputation, unicoins, april-fools

I purchased a reputation increase with unicoins, and while it increased my reputation in my top bar, the rep is still the old amount in the stack exchange drop down. The drop down appears to be getting it's information from the wrong database.

Comment: UnicornDB is still in pre-delta... This should take 0.6 to 0.8 years...

Comment: The developers who need to update the stackexchange server are on out to catch unicorns. Please be patient.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this is the huge amount of purchases. As soon as the servers finished handling all the requests, the cache updates will follow.

Comment: How long does it take to update?

Comment: Until the 2nd of April!

Answer (score 0):

Since you purchase the "reputation increase" it increased it in the top bar, but since someone else purchased "Cut everyones rep", it kept it the same in the drop down..

Since it takes a while for things to fall down, the top bar should also reach the level of the drop down by tomorrow.